# Is there some shared structure between Chaitin's constants of similar systems?

Tags: turing-machines, chaitin-constant

Since it is possible to [approximate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1699366/can-we-know-the-first-few-digits-of-chaitins-constant) [Chaitin's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant) ($\Omega$) for some systems, is it known whether these numbers are somehow related to another when considering similarly operating Turing Machines?

Say, is the halting probability value for the (24,2)-[Universal Turing Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_machine) (UTM) somehow connected to the one for the (2,18)-UTM, and less connected to a specific different turing machine that has a very different style of computation?